# Google Sheets COUNT number of occurrences based on the DAY of the DATE, disregard month and year of the date

Tags: google-sheets, formula, countif

I need to count a number of occurrences for each day in a month, but the formula must not include month and year because I need to reuse it every month.

I have a table with rows and columns like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ... 31
```

Under each of these dates I need to inserted the counted number of occurrences for that day of the month.

Comment: Could you give a bit more info about the layout of your data plz, preferably an example.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=sumproduct(--(day($B2:$B)=E1))
```

I happened to have some dates lying around. Here's a sample.

[image]

[Linked spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XSETlNMbHIb_aMaLgQO3AX7OEZjo9iiGy8aa7HpAwJA/edit?usp=sharing)